# Why do I get this fabric put error?

Tags: python, linux, fabric

So I am trying to move a specific file from my computer onto the remote server. However, when I try to use fab to do this it returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: put() encountered an exception while uploading '/home/jonathan/Dropbox/facebook-crawler/worker_scraper.py'
Underlying exception:  
    size mismatch in put!  0 != 7304
```

Fab function:

```
@roles('workers')
def move_scraper():
    put('~/Dropbox/facebook-crawler/worker_scraper.py', '~/facebook-crawler/')
```

anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? There were some issues with early versions doing just this. This is likely an issue in the underlying Paramiko library.

Comment: silly, but for prosperity: make sure the target box:disk has space available :)

Comment: @RickyA This seems to have been my problem. Also, I believe put() temporarily stores the file somewhere. There needs to be space here as well. (I have lots of space at destination path but limited space outside this path)

Comment: @RickyA you should add an answer. ;)

Comment: also, please consider checking the permissions

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I should add an official answer.  I ran into this error on a Raspberry Pi (had never seen it through quite a bit of experience with Fabric).

**I was out of disk space**